# google street view not showing

Tags: objective-c, google-maps, google-street-view

I have a view controller on it I've placed a UIView that should show a streetview when a button is clicked

```
GMSPanoramaView *streetView;

-(void) viewdidAppear
{
...
streetView = [[GMSPanoramaView alloc] initWithFrame: self.googleStreetView.frame];
    self.googleStreetView = streetView; //self.googleStreetView located on the view controller in story board design time
}
- (IBAction)openGoogleStreetView:(id)sender
{
    //initialize streetview
    [streetView moveNearCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude, longitude)];
    [self.tableView bringSubviewToFront:self.googleStreetView];
}
```

Comment: So where exactly do you add `self.googleStreetView` to your `UIView`?

Comment: @Jasper in storyboard

Comment: As a subView of your tableView?

Comment: I'm suspecting that your streetView is not added to your view. Could you try to change `self.googleStreetView = streetView;` to `[self.googleStreetView addSubview:streetView];`

Comment: Good! Glad I could help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll just post an answer here for the record.

Doing `self.googleStreetView = streetView;` will just put the pointer of `streetView` to `self.googleStreetView` but will not add it to your UI.

You need to add `streetView` as a `subView` of `self.googleStreetView`

```
[self.googleStreetView addSubview:streetView];
```